# Output in jinja loop two parameters

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I'm developing with Django.  The output data is passed to the html page as follows:

```
def page(request): 
    data = { 'name':[
                    'nameOne',               
                    'nameTwo', 
                    'nameThree'
                    ], 
             'id':[
                  '1',
                  '2',
                   '3'
                  ]
           }
    return render(  request, "mainpageapp/page.html", data)
```

I would like to see a link with text name and value id

```
 <a href="/{{id}}">{{name}}</a>
```

At the moment I can only output one element in the for loop

```
{% for el in name %} 

  <a href="/{{el}}">{{el}}</a><br> 

{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to display two dictionary elements in one forloop?  Or some other way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip the two into a single iterable:

```
def page(request):
    name = ['nameOne', 'nameTwo', 'nameThree']
    ids = ['1', '2', '3']
    data = zip(ids, name)
    context = {'data': data}
    return render(request, 'mainpageapp/page.html', context)
```

in the template, we then enumerate with:

```
{% for pk, name in data %} 
  <a href="/{{ pk }}">{{ name }}</a><br> 
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `id`, it overrides the reference to the [**`id`** builtin function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). Use for example `ids`.